# Configuring /etc/hosts to run an application

Tags: linux, nginx, hostname

I am using nginx, until now I was running my php applications on /usr/share/nginx/html which is the default document root when nginx is installed on centOS and like systems.

Now I had to create server blocks (or virtual hosts) to run another application, followed this tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) and ended up creating my application in /var/www/html.

On this process, as the tutorial states to edit etc/hosts to your public IP, this made another application run that is deployed on my LAN. I wanted it to run on my machine only, so I changed it to my local IP and made the following entry to hosts

```
192.168.0.38 dev.mysite.com www.dev.mysite.com
```

Strangely, just after that I noticed my hostname had changed to

```
muUsername@dev instead of @localhost before
```

1. Please tell me why it happened and how to change it back.
2. Now the application runs when I access localhost in the browser, but not when I access dev.mysite.com, How to fix that?
3. On accessing www.dev.mysite.com I get my old application at the old webroot (uss/share/nginx/html) Why is this happening and how to fix this?

Need any more information, please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It happens because you are setting up a FQDN for your machine and the hostname is assumed to be the subdomain part in this case. That's due to the behaviour of [gethostname](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_gethostname.htm) function.
If you run `hosname -f` it will give you the FQDN and `hostname -d` will give you the domain name. Set your machine's name before all these FQDN.

**Update** : Didn't pay attention you were on centos, updated the second file location

/etc/hosts :

```
192.168.0.38 mymachine dev.mysite.com www.dev.mysite.com
```

/etc/sysconfig/network:

```
HOSTNAME=mymachine
```

Then **reboot**.

2) When you hit that domain name locally, the kernel will look for `/etc/hosts` content at some point  and then route the request to your loopback interface. You probably missed a server name in your nginx configuration.

3) Change your document root path for this server name.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.dev.mysite.com;
    root /var/www/dev.mysite.com;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 http://www.dev.mysite.com;
}
```

Comment: Made the changes, but now when I access dev.mysite.com, I get the old webRoot (usr/share/nginx/html) and on accessing localhost, I get the page application stored at /var/www/html! I put in the mymachine at /etc/hostname and in /etc/hosts but the hostname hasnt changed on relog.

Comment: Oh yeah, CentOS. Change the hostname in /etc/hosts and /etc/sysconfig/network (for this last one set it with HOSTNAME=mymachine) and **REBOOT**. Remove /etc/hostname, that's for debian. For the nginx part, it's not really the place here, ask on serverfault. Check updated answer.

Comment: HOSTNAME is correct there!

Comment: @user1502178 Reboot.